# Getting book pages in same level like getting child pages

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a book called `courses` with several subpages, I want to show the list of ot other subpages when one subpage is open.

Example:

```
-Courses
---Course1
---Course2
---Course3
---course4
```

I want to show course1, course2 & course3 when course4 is open. I know to get childpages, but have no idea how to get pages in same level. I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

If book module is enabled, it also creates a block called "Book navigation". You can display the block in any of the "Region" defined in your theme (e.g. "Sidebar first" in Bartik theme), by visiting `http://your-site-url/admin/structure/block`.

The block will be displayed(in the selected region) whenever you open the book page. And by default it will show the the book pages at the same level(sibling) pages.